# How can RAII be applied for class members that require extended initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, raii

As far as I understand the RAII idiom when applied to resources needed by a class (and please correct me if I'm wrong), a class that requires a resource should define a member of the appropriate type, and its destructor will be called automatically when the using class instance is destroyed, like this:

```
class Skybox
{
    public:
        Skybox() : tex_(...) {}

    private:
        Texture tex_;
};
```

Apart from using a smart pointer to allocate the resource on the heap, how can this pattern be applied if the resource member requires some code to be executed in the `Skybox` constructor, before the initialisation of the resource? For example:

```
class Skybox
{
    public:
        Skybox(const std::string& fileName);

    private:
        Texture tex_;
}

Skybox::Skybox(const std::string& fileName)
{
    // read stuff from skybox initialization file
    // including various texture parameters such as texture file
    ...
    // initialize tex_ based on information read above
}
```

Update: the `Texture` class requires all initialization to be performed in its constructor (i.e. no `Texture::Init()` method is available)

Comment: Does the `Texture` class allow later initialization, like `tex_.init(...)`?

Comment: No, it does not. I will update the question text.

Comment: Is there any pre-computation that needs to be used for anything other than initializing tex? If not, just create a constructor for Texture that takes a filename and does all of that processing as part of its own initialization.

Comment: You are coupling oddly here.  `Skybox` doesn't need to know anything about filepaths.  `Skybox` only needs to be passed in a `Texture`.  Let `Texture` or a further abstraction handle your knowledge of the file system.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I am also reading a skybox initialization file. I will update the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap the initialization code into a function, and use that function (member or non-member, static or non-static, as appropriate) to initialize the member variable:

```
Texture Skybox::init_tex(std::string const& fileName) {
  // read stuff from file, including textureFile
  // initialize result
  return Texture(...);
}

Skybox::Skybox(std::string const& fileName):
  tex_(init_tex(fileName))
{ }
```

The initialization function should probably be a static function. If it isn't, be careful not to use any members that haven't been initialized yet — you're calling `init_tex` on a not-yet-fully initialized `Skybox` instance.

Comment: Nice. Should that be a static function, to be safe?

Comment: Using non-static member functions in the constructor requires a lot of care and non-local guarantees. A static member function would obviate all those worries.

Comment: I don't really agree with this. The loading of the `Texture` shouldn't be coupled to the `Skybox`. I'd rather have a free function to do this.

Comment: @Pmr, if the texture could be created solely from a file name, then we might expect it to have a constructor that accepts a file name. Instead, it seems there are some skybox-specific aspects to how a texture is loaded from a file — maybe the texture is embedded in a special "skybox" file format.

Comment: @RobKennedy I guess we would need to make more about the involved classes. But as OP has accepted your answer, it seems you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should encapsulate the creation of a texture into a free function as the reading of the file seems unrelated to the Skybox and could possibly useful somewhere else. I guess another name for this is `Factory`.

```
Tex tex_from_file(const std::string&) {
  // ...
}

class Skybox {
  Skybox(const std::string& s) : tex_(tex_from_file(s)) {}
};
```

Even nicer would be a Skybox constructible from a `Tex`
object. However, this requires `Tex` to be copy or move
constructible. If this isn't the case a proper workaround could be to
return a `std::unique_ptr<Tex>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++11 features (variadic templates and perfect forwarding), this can be achieved thanks to a template constructor :

```
#include <utility>
template<class T>
class raii_wrapper
{
    public:

template<typename... Arg>
    raii_wrapper(Arg&&... args) : obj(std::forward<Arg>(args)...) {}

    private:
        T obj;
};

struct foo
{
    foo(){}
};

struct foo_1
{
    foo_1(int){}
};

struct foo_2
{
    foo_2(int,int&){}
};

int main()
{
    raii_wrapper<foo> f;
    raii_wrapper<foo_1> f1(1);
    int i(3);
    raii_wrapper<foo_2> f2(1,i);
    return 0;
}
```

In C++03/98, template constructor is still the solution (but boost shall help for variadic template and argument passing). See implementations of functions like make_share_ptr.

Comment: Could you please change your code so it relates directly to the `Skybox` and `Texture` classes in the example?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Texture` class has a default constructor and supports swapping, you can initialize the resource with a local variable and swap it at the end of the constructor.

```
Skybox::Skybox(const std::string& fileName)
{
    Texture localTex(fileName);
    //...
    tex_.swap(localTex);
}
```